# Vue.js - Unit testing component with complex children

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, vue.js, bootstrap-4

Let's assume a basic [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) driven HTML form as part of a custom Vue component `MyForm.vue`

```
<template>
  <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">Email address</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </form>
</template>
```

A unit test for testing if the template is rendered successfully is pretty simple

```
describe('MyForm', () => {

  let wrapper;

  beforeEach(...);

  it('Should be rendered', () => {

    let field = wrapper.find('#email');
    expect(field.element.value).toEqual('');
  });
});
```

This line works `field.element.value` works because `field.element` is of native type `HtmlInputElement` with `value` attribute.

What if I want access an attribute of a complex component let's say of [b-form-input](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/form-input), the Bootstrap-Vue's default input element? `b-form-input` is of type `BFormInput` how to deal with it? Just cast the `HtmlElement` to `BFormInput`?

```
<template>
  <b-form>
    <b-form-group label="Email">
      <b-form-input type="email" id="email"></b-form-input>
    </b-form-group>
    <b-button type="submit" variant="primary">Submit</button>
  </b-form>
</template>
```

How to test non-native components? Specially with type-safety means TypeScript. Any ideas?

**Edit 03/01/2020**

Following up to [muka.gergely](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2316540/muka-gergely)'s answer I found [this](https://medium.com/js-dojo/when-to-unstub-a-component-in-a-vue-js-unit-test-608c7d1c646) article. `shallowMount` is stubbing all child components by default which prevents also event handling. Moreover `shallowMount` allows to manually *unstub* components, in my case to unstub `b-form` and `b-button` for submit event testing.

```
const stubs = { // Originally intended to provide custom stubs, here used to unstub components
  BButton,
  BForm,
};

wrapper = shallowMount<MyComponent>(MyComponent, {stubs});
```

This effects that these components are rendered instead of stubbed. All remaining components like the `b-form-input` are still automatically stubbed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to `mount` the elements before testing them. You don't test the **Vue** component that you wrote, but the rendered output.

You should add **vue-test-utils** then your unit testing library (**Jest** and **Mocha** are well supported).

- You can find **vue-test-utils** here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vue/test-utils
- More on **Vue** unit testing: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/unit-testing.html
- More on **vue-test-utils**: https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/guides/#getting-started

Here's a basic unit test for **App.vue** (with **Vuetify** and **vue-router**):

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import { shallowMount, createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import App from '@/App';

Vue.use(Vuetify)

const localVue = createLocalVue()
localVue.use(VueRouter)
const router = new VueRouter()

describe('App.vue', () => {
    let vuetify

    beforeEach(() => {
        vuetify = new Vuetify()
    })

    it('mounts and renders', () => {
        const wrapper = shallowMount(App, { localVue, vuetify, router });

        expect(wrapper.html()).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

You can see that I used `shallowMount()` as I wasn't interested in testing the children of **App.vue** (they all have their separate unit tests). If I had been, then I should've used `mount()` instead.

Comment: Yea, I already used `shallowMount`... Does this mean I'm not interrested in the rendered output during unit tests?

Comment: **shallowMount** renders only the component being tested, not the **child components**.